# Read particular xml file in Java

Tags: java, xml, file, parsing

I would read and parse two file in Java. The first one is as the following:

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">name123</field>
        <field name="date">1998-01-06 03:31:00</field>
        <field name="text"> text text text </field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

The second one, instead, is as the following:

```
<top>

<title>
title title

<documents>
nameDocument1
</top>

<top>

<title>
title title title

<documents>
nameDocument1
nameDocument2
</top>
```

I must read two objects with the variables `"id", "data" and "text"` for the first one, and `"title", "listDocument"` for the second one.

I've tried XML parser, can anyone help me to realize a Java solution to read them?

Comment: If you have tried an XML parser (which one?) please share your try in the question and point out where you have run into a problem.

Comment: ....... otherwise your question is much too broad and in essence is asking for someone to write a personal tutorial just for you.

Comment: The second is not valid XML, because there are no closing tags for `<title>` and `<documents>`. So a normal XML parser will almost certainly fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your file path and everything will be ok

```
   public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

        File fXmlFile = new File("//test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("doc");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("field").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Date : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("field").item(1).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Text : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("field").item(2).getTextContent());

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the output : 
  First Name : name123
  Date : 1998-01-06 03:31:00
  Text :  text text text

Comment: Great! Thank you for your solution!